# Cordova iOS: create a file in cordova.file.* directory using file-API

Tags: ios, file-io, directory, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

As of cordova file API v1.2.0 URLs to important file-system directories are provided using predefined cordova.file.* constants. If I try to create a new file in any of the cordova predefined directory (e.g.  cordova.file.dataDirectory) I alwas get an error with code 5 when trying to call function "getFile". The file is not created.

My JavaScript code is following:

```
function FSready(fileSystem) {
    gFileSystem = fileSystem;
    gFileRoot = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    filepathx = gFileRoot + "csdtest.txt";
    gFileSystem.root.getFile(filepathx, {create: true, exclusive: false}, fileCreated, FSfail);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, FSready, FSfail);
}
```

I am only able to create file without providing any path to file at all like this:

```
gFileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, fileCreated, FSfail);
```

In this case, file is always (in simulator) created in directory

```
file:///Users/mac/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/EB4E48F9-69F9-4CE9-AD3E-6E949071BC2D/Library/NoCloud/csdtest.txt
```

In config.xml I have the following:

```
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

I also tried to run this code on iPad with the same results. I am on Cordova 3.5.0 with iOS 7.1 and the plugin versions I am using are org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.2-dev "File" and org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.8-dev "File Transfer".

Thanks for help!